# BigQuery time zone conversion

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to translate a timezone conversion query from bigquery to presto, the existing bigquery syntax is as the following:

```
timestamp(datetime('2019-07-01'), 'US/Pacific')
```

but is this bigquery syntax incorrect to begin with? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is correct.

Also, consider below - depends on what exactly output you expect

TIMESTAMP('2019-07-01', 'US/Pacific')

or

DATETIME('2019-07-01', 'US/Pacific')

The syntax is

```
TIMESTAMP(
  string_expression[, timezone] |
  date_expression[, timezone] |
  datetime_expression[, timezone]
)
```

or

```
DATETIME(timestamp_expression [, timezone])
```

Comment: thanks for the advise, so I ran the query in the following variations with results: 

TIMESTAMP(DATETIME('2019-07-01'), 'US/Pacific') --> 2019-07-01 07:00:00

TIMESTAMP('2019-07-01', 'US/Pacific') --> 2019-07-01 07:00:00

DATETIME('2019-07-01', 'US/Pacific') --> 2019-06-30 17:00:00

seems like TIMESTAMP just adding the absolute hour of the timezone difference to the date, and DATETIME subtracting the timezone difference.

Comment: as I mentioned in my answer - "depends on what exactly output you expect" and what exactly your use case. Meantime the question was about bigquery syntax and it happens to be correct  :o)